# How do I handle an unspecified number of parameters in Scheme?

Tags: function, scheme, variadic-functions, variadic

For example `((fn-stringappend string-append) "a" "b" "c")`  I know how to handle this `(f x y z)`. But what if there's an unknown number of parameters? Is there any way to handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Scheme you can use the dot notation for declaring a procedure that receives a variable number of arguments (also known as *varargs* or [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)):

```
(define (procedure . args)
  ...)
```

Inside `procedure`, `args` will be a list with the zero or more arguments passed; call it like this:

```
(procedure "a" "b" "c")
```

As pointed out by @Arafinwe, here's the equivalent notation for an anonymous procedure:

```
(lambda args ...)
```

Call it like this:

```
((lambda args ...) "a" "b" "c")
```

Remember that if you need to pass the parameters in a list of unknown size to a variadic function you can write it like this:

```
(apply procedure '("a" "b" "c"))
(apply (lambda args ...) '("a" "b" "c"))
```

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the code in the comments, this won't work as you intend:

```
(define (fp f)
  (lambda (.z)
    (f .z)))
```

I believe you meant this:

```
(define (fp f)
  (lambda z
    (apply f z)))
```

With a bit of syntactic sugar the above procedure can be further simplified to this:

```
(define ((fp f) . z)
  (apply f z))
```

But that's just a long way for simply writing:

```
(apply f z)
```

Is this what you need?

```
(apply string-append '("a" "b" "c"))
```

Because anyway that's equivalent to the following:

```
(string-append "a" "b" "c")
```

`string-append` *already* receives zero or more arguments (at least, that's the case in Racket)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Óscar López's answer, you can also make an anonymous function of variable arguments like so:

```
(lambda args ...)
```

Where again, inside the `lambda`, `args` is a list of the arguments passed.

Comment: (define (fp f)
         (lambda (.z)
           (f .z)))     f contains unknown number of parameter. what wrong with my code or Do I have to do like z ...

Comment: The "dot" is separate from the name of the argument.