# Several lists as an input for a function

Tags: scheme

I'm defining a function (*"my-function"* below) making use of three lists. 
It checks if those three lists satisfy a certain condition and then do something more. This condition is to have length 2 (I suspect this is not important but I prefer to mention it). Therefore, it has the form:

```
(define my-function (lambda (list1 list2 list3)
    (cond                                                                            
     [(and (= (length list1) 2) (= (length list2) 2) (= (length list3) 2))...
```

My question is: how could I generalize "my-function" to a number of lists?

More generally: is there a way to index the lists into the input of the function and then call them one-by-one to check the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`andmap`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) to check whether a condition holds for *all* elements in a list:

```
(define lsts (list list1 list2 list3 list4))
(andmap (lambda (lst) (= (length lst) 2))
        lsts)
```

The trick is to create a list with the elements that you want to check, in this case, they're lists themselves. And to generalise this even more, you could pass the `lambda` that does the checking as a parameter, and you could pass the sublists as variable arguments:

```
(define (my-function check . lsts)
  (andmap check lsts))

(my-function (lambda (lst) (= (length lst) 2))
             list1 list2 list3 list4)
```

Comment: @PetSerAl you're right, thank you for catching that! It's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I had never seen "check . lsts" as an input. What is doing that dot in the middle?

Comment: `check` and `lsts` are just parameter names. `check` is a function and `lsts` is a list of lists, the dot in the middle is for declaring a variable number of arguments, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658435/201359).

Comment: I'll do it. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Now my question is: how do I work with every pair? Is there a way to call every list into the list of lists? for example: (define (my-function lst) (make-list (second lst) (first lst)) lsts) would work?

Comment: That’s worth a new question. Check the ‘map’ procedure, I think it’s what you need.