# I do not understand why a lambda scheme is working

Tags: lambda, syntax, scheme, lisp

I'm totally new to scheme, coming from a c# background.

I thought I was getting a handle on lambda, but I don't understand why this example works:

```
(let ([f (lambda x x)]) (f 1 2 3 4) )
```

The answer is (1 2 3 4), but how? It's the *x x* part that I don't get. The lambda takes no parameters so the body is *x x*, right? But I don't know what that means in this case, can someone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, the `lambda` in your code *is* receiving parameters, and an aribtrary number of them. The syntax for a `lambda` with no parameters is different:

```
(let ([f (lambda () 1)]) (f))
=> 1
```

The `lambda` expression in the question is something else:

```
(lambda x x)
```

It receives a variable number of arguments as a list, and then returns them. You named it `f`, and when it's invoked like this:

```
(f 1 2 3 4)
```

All of the arguments get bound to `x`, a *list* and then the value of `x` is returned:

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

So, `f` is nothing more than an *identity* function that receives multiple arguments. Perhaps this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658435/201359) will clarify how variadic functions are defined in Scheme. For completeness' sake, here's an example of a `lambda` that receives a *single* argument and returns it:

```
(let ([f (lambda (x) x)]) (f 1))
=> 1
```

So there you have it, that's how we define `lambda`s that receive 0, 1 or many parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, and for the link as well. I am reading the book _The Scheme Programming Language_ by R. Kent Dybvig and I am not quite grasping all of its the explanations when it comes to things like lists. And concepts like pairs, cells, and others. If you could recommend another book it would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course! The Little Schemer, How to Design Programs and SICP are the best books for learning how to think in Scheme.

Comment: When I returned to the office yesterday, I found The Little Schemer at my desk, courtesy of a coworker. I like it already. I will check out the other title, many thanks. :)

Comment: How cool! For me the best book is SICP, it's a classic. A bit more advanced, but it'll teach you not only the language, but how to build an interpreter and a compiler for it (!). And it's a first-year book for some universities.

Comment: @THedge [Tourezky's CL: a Gentle Intro to Symbolic Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook) spends a lot of time on list structure, i.e. pairs and such. *a lot*. with *diagrams*. highly recommended for a beginner. If you want concepts *explained* to you, stay clear from the Little books.

Comment: @will-ness thank you, I will download the original version. I definitely want to understand concepts.

Answer (score 2):

A `lambda` syntax is like this:

```
(lambda argument-list body ...)
```

Looking at your lambda:

```
(lambda x x)
```

Thus the argument list is `x` and the body of the lambda is `x`.

A list in Scheme looks like `(a b c)`, but it is really `(a . (b . (c . ())))` and in a procedure argument list if the chain ends up in a symbol, like `(a b . c)` then the procedure takes 2 arguments **or more**. The "rest" arguments are accumulated in a list called `c`. In ES6 it's the same as `(a, b, ...c) => expression`. Now if you have no mandatory argument, eg. you allow 0 or more arguments, the argument list is just a symbol. eg `(lambda x x)` is the same as `(...x) => x`.

I believe in C# instead of `x` one would have written `params type[] x`. C# doesn't do anonymous lambda + rest argument so I hope you know some ES6.

Comment: Thank you also for the explanation, it all helps.Yes, in c# _params_ allows you to specify a variable number of parameters, it appears at the end of a procedure's parameter list.

Comment: Meant to say a method's parameter list in my previous answer. And thanks for the info about the dot notation. The dot notation is an example of one of the things that, in my opinion, is not well explained in the book that I mentioned I am reading. (In my answer to Oscar.)

Comment: Since you know C# you should try to implement a Scheme subset interpreter in C# after you know how to do it in Scheme. With Scheme in Scheme lots of stuff are easy since you use the host language, but in C# you learn what the primitives and system needs to do to make it work. I'm a big fan of the [SICP videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY&index=1&list=PL8FE88AA54363BC46) presented by the magicians themselves.

Comment: I will check out the videos you referenced, thank you!