# How do non-binary foldl and foldr work in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, fold

I'm familiar with the underlying workings and differences of `foldl` and `foldr` over a single list. However, in Racket, you can use folds on multiple lists. For example, you can find the difference of elements in two lists by writing

```lisp
; (mapMinus '(3 4) '(1 2)) => '(2 2)
(define (mapMinus lst0 lst1)
  (foldl (λ (hd0 hd1 acc) (cons (- hd0 hd1) acc)) '() lst0 lst1))
```

How exactly do Racket's implementations of `foldl` and `foldr` work to handle multiple lists? The Racket source code for `foldl` is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/racket/racket/blob/2643a75ce3b92e42f6a77769a03e91b095683e42/racket/collects/racket/private/list.rkt#L228), but I don't know Chez Scheme well enough to understand it.

Comment: I don't grok your question. Do you need help understanding the code in your post, or the code in the linked `foldl` procedure from Chez Scheme? or do you ask about `fold`s that apply to multiple lists in general?

Comment: Are you asking about the behavior of `foldl` and how to use it with multiple lists, or are you asking about how to implement an arbitrary-arity `foldl` function yourself?

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion! I was just writing that function as an example of Racket using fold over multiple lists to make it obvious this was a question about Racket's unique folds rather than a question about how folds work in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `fold` that operates over multiple lists simply applies its `lambda` element-wise on all of the lists, simultaneously. Perhaps a simplified implementation (with no error checking, etc.) of it will make things clearer; let's compare a standard implementation of `foldr` (which IMHO is slightly simpler to understand than `foldl`):

```
(define (foldr proc init lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      init
      (proc (car lst)
            (foldr proc init (cdr lst)))))
```

With an implementation that accepts multiple lists:

```
(define (foldr proc init . lst) ; lst is a list of lists
  (if (null? (car lst)) ; all lists assumed to be of same length
      init
      ; use apply because proc can have any number of args
      (apply proc
             ; append, list are required for building the parameter list
             ; in the right way so it can be passed to (apply proc ...)
             (append (map car lst)
                     ; use apply again because it's a variadic procedure
                     (list (apply foldr proc init (map cdr lst)))))))
```

All the extra code in the multi-list version is for applying `proc` to multiple elements at the same time, getting the current element of each list `(map car lst)` and advancing over all the lists `(map cdr lst)`.

Also the implementation needs to take into account that the procedure operates over a [variable number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12658406/201359) of lists, assuming that the provided `lambda` receives the correct number of arguments (number of input lists + 1). It works as expected:

```
(foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc)
         (cons (list e1 e2) acc))
       '()
       '(1 2 3)
       '(4 5 6))

=> '((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really are asking is how to create a variadic function in Scheme/Racket. The answer is given at https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html, but let me just give you a quick example:

```
(define (foo a b . xs)
  (+ a b (length xs)))
```

would be equivalent to

```
def foo(a, b, *xs):
  return a + b + len(xs)
```

in Python. `xs` here is a list value containing the rest of the arguments.

The second piece of puzzle is, how to apply a variadic function with a list value. For that, you can use `apply`. Read more at https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29. Again, here's a quick example:

```
(define (foo a b c) (+ a b c))
(apply foo 1 '(2 3))
;; equivalent to (foo 1 2 3)
```

would be equivalent to

```
def foo(a, b, c): return a + b + c
foo(1, *[2, 3]) ;; equivalent to foo(1, 2, 3)
```

With these, creating a fold that accepts multiple arguments is just a programming exercise:

```
(define (my-fold proc accum required-first-list . list-of-optional-lists)
  ... IMPLEMENT FOLD HERE ...)
```

Note that if you read the source code of Racket (which uses Chez Scheme), you will see that it uses `case-lambda` instead of defining the function directly. `case-lambda` is just a way to make the code more efficient for common usage of fold (i.e., a fold with only one list).